# HowTo rename a file in unix by dropping the last occurrence of a string between 2 characters

Tags: regex, unix, rename

I have a list of files in a directory with the following pattern:
`my-file-1-xxxyy-all.txt`
`file-2-xx-all.txt`
`ThirdFile-xxxx-all.txt`

I would like to rename the files by replacing the last occurrence of the pattern "-*-" by "-":

So the desired result would be
`my-file-1-all.txt`
`file-2-all.txt`
`ThirdFile-all.txt`

What would be the best way to achieve this under unix?

Thanks much

Comment: Have you tried anything like `rename` or `mv` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this :

```
rename -n 's/-[^-]+-all\./-all./' *txt
```

Remove `-n` switch when the output looks good.

[image: warning] **There are other tools with the same name which may or may not be able to do this, so be careful.**

If you run the following command (`GNU`)

```
$ file "$(readlink -f "$(type -p rename)")"
```

and you have a result that contains `Perl script, ASCII text executable` and not containing `ELF`, then this seems to be the right tool =)

If not, to make it the default (usually already the case) on `Debian` and derivative like `Ubuntu` :

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --set rename /path/to/rename
```

Replace `/path/to/rename` to the path of your `perl rename` executable.

---

If you don't have this command, search your package manager to install it or [do it manually](https://web.archive.org/web/20130625192518/https://metacpan.org/module/RMBARKER/File-Rename-0.20/rename.PL) (no deps...)

---

<sub><sup>This tool was originally written by Larry Wall, the Perl's dad.</sup></sub>

Answer (score 0):

```
for f in *; do mv $f `echo $f | sed 's/-.*-([^-]*)$/-\1/'`; done
```

Comment: Please stop using backticks in 2018, use `$( )`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, the regex used doesn't take the last occurrence;   ``my-file-1-all.txt``   turns into   ``my-all.txt``